# Restricting access to Azure web role

Tags: authentication, azure, ravendb

I've deployed RavenDB to Azure and run it under IIS in one web role.

Now I would like to restrict access to it to either another web roles / worker roles or certain admin users.

What are the possible options and their pros and cons?

Here's what I've managed to find out up to now:

1. I know that RavenDB supports Windows authentication, but I've read that it's difficult to use it in Azure. Is it possible to create a local user on web role start up?
2. Can I somehow use Azure ACL to restrict access to the RavenDB web role?
3. Should I use certificates?
4. Should I start reading about federated identity?
5. I don't think I can restrict access by IP as I want to be able to create new roles and also access db role from the internet.

I would prefer a solution that wouldn't stop / hider me from spinning up new instances of web / worker roles that need to talk to my db role.

Comment: If the roles that you want to allow access to RavenDB are all in the same deployment as that machine, then opening just an internal endpoint on the RavenDB role will achieve this.

Comment: @RichardAstbury - but I also want a certain people to be able to access management studio from the internet...

Comment: Perhaps the new auth options in RavenDB just announced will help?  https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d87a67d0b1a516c

Comment: @MattJohnson - will look at it - what a timing! ;-)